# Erro ao importar projeto Eclipse para Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, importação, android-manifest

Toda vez que vou importar meu projeto "Radio__SantAna" do Eclipse para o Android Studio,  retorna este erro:

```
* C:\Users\Cliente\AndroidImageSlideShow\AndroidManifest.xml:
Invalid XML file: C:\Users\Cliente\AndroidImageSlideShow\AndroidManifest.xml:
Premature end of file.
```

Como migrar corretamente?

**Android Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rs.player"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
        <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
         >
        <activity
            android:name=".Home"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
                <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar" 
                    android:label="@string/app_name" 
                    android:name=".Listen" 
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait" class=".Ouvir" />
          <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" 
                    android:label="@string/app_name" 
                    android:name=".SplashNews" 
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait" class=".SplashActivity" />
            <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" 
                    android:label="@string/app_name" 
                    android:name=".DetailActivity" 
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait" class=".DetailActivity" />
              <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" 
                    android:label="@string/app_name" 
                    android:name=".ListActivity" 
                    android:configChanges="orientation"
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait" class=".ListActivity" />
              <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" 
                    android:label="@string/app_name" 
                    android:name=".SendMessage" 
                    android:configChanges="orientation"
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait" class=".SendMessageActivity" />
              <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" 
                    android:label="@string/app_name" 
                    android:name=".FormActivity" 
                    android:configChanges="orientation"
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait" class=".FormActivity" />
              <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" 
                    android:label="@string/app_name" 
                    android:name=".InviteActivity" 
                    android:configChanges="orientation"
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait" class=".InviteActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Pode colocar o texto do `AndroidManifest.xml` para que possamos ajudar?

Comment: não sei qual esta dizendo?

Comment: Eu estava comparando o seu manifest com um manifest de um projeto que eu fiz em grupo, e não consegui encontrar falha alguma no seu. Você fez os arquivos `build.gradle` pelo ADT para importar para o Studio?

Comment: eu importei direto

Comment: Pode ser esse o problema. Faça pelo ADT a criação dos arquivos `.gradle` e então importe os projetos do ADT pelos arquivos `.gradle`

Comment: como que faço isso?

Comment: Dê um clique direito no projeto, e vá na opção `Export...`, então va em `Android` e daí, `Generate Gradle build files`. Então é só importar os arquivos gerados, no Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu consegui fazer a adaptação manualmente. Primeiramente, apenas abri o projeto. E no próprio Android Studio criei um arquivo chamado **build.gradle** (o que precisava, na pasta raiz do projeto).
Código:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Achei uma forma mais fácil e rápido para migrar. Como está acima, está um pouco desatualizado. No caso, tive que mudar a `classpath` para a versão mínima de `1.0` (sem o sinal de +). Mudei tbm a versão de construção, mas isso é particularidade, por causa da minha aplicação, necessita-se de uma versão mais recente. Aqui está a fonte:http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-from-intellij-projects que serviu basicamente na etapa inicial da mudança para o `Intellij`.