# Erro ao executar uma app no Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Importei um projeto do eclipse para o Android Studio (versão 1.3.2), até ai tudo certo, mas ocorreu umm erro quando tentei executar o programa:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':dexDebug'.
>    com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Alguém pode me ajudar a resolver esse problema?

Comment: Já tentou atualizar a versão do Android Studio? a versão corrente é 1.51.

Comment: Para migrar o projeto também precisa ser feito algumas alterações, dê uma olhada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47417/erro-ao-importar-projeto-eclipse-para-android-studio

Comment: Sim, já tentei a atualizar, porém continua dando o mesmo erro.

Comment: Eu já criei os arquivos gradles do projeto.

Comment: Eu começaria instalando o Java 7, que é a versão com suporte do Android.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta o seguinte:

no gradle do teu projeto dentro das dependencies adiciona:

```
dependencies {
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

dentro de android faz

```
android {
 dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

 defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

Depois volta a sincronizar o gradle seguido de um clean ao projeto.